# Xcode runs old version of app on device

Tags: ios, xcode

I can test on the simulators, but both my iPhone and iPad show old versions of my app.  I've tried deleting derived data, deleting the apps from the devices, and cleaning the project. My phone is on 8.3 and my iPad is on 8.1.2, and I have the problem on both devices.  Xcode is on 6.1.1.  I'm running 10.10.2 Yosemite.  Please help.

Comment: Is it safe to assume you are connecting the devices to a Mac by USB cable, picking the device from the target selector, and pressing XCode's Run button? Is the device listed as a valid development device in the Organizer window?

Comment: yes to all the questions.

Comment: I recreated my provisioning profiles today as well and still the same issue.  It appears to load normally, but it's always an old version.  I don't know where it's getting it from.

Comment: I finally created an entirely new app id and new project and copied all my files over to it.  Now it works on my devices.  **sigh**  No idea what went wrong.